# ggvis colorbar (or ggplot2) without any margin

Tags: css, r, ggplot2, shiny, ggvis

Does anyone know how to make an color bar in `ggvis` or `ggplot2` without any margins? `ggvis` is preferred since I am putting this in a `shiny` application.

I have a partially working example in ggplot2:

data:

```
legendData <- c(100, 325, 550, 775, 1000)
legendColors <- c("#FF9DEB", "#9FC5FF", "#00E4D0", "#AAD44D", "#FFAE85")
df <- data.frame(x = legendData, col = legendColors, y = 1:5, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

theme_nothing() comes from `ggmap` and you can copy the function from [here](https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/blob/efb7da291ea8172b68765a11a4f9a1619b6ffab1/R/theme_nothing.R).

ggplot2 (has margins):

```
ggplot(df, aes(y = 1, x = x, fill = col)) + geom_tile() + 
scale_fill_identity() + theme_nothing()
```

Running this gives me this **[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFyXE.jpg)**. Unfortunately this still has margins.

I have some `ggvis` code but it is no longer working. It gives me the error "Scales must all be countable, or not countable".

ggvis (not working):

```
df %>% ggvis(~y, ~x, fill := ~col) %>% 
layer_rects(width = band(), height = band()) %>%
scale_nominal("x", padding = 0, points = FALSE) %>%
scale_nominal("y", padding = 0, points = FALSE) %>%
add_axis("y", title = "", properties = axis_props(labels = list(fontSize = 14))) %>%
add_axis("x", title = "") %>% set_options(width = 25, height = 100)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your `ggvis` code runs if you use factors/characters for `x` and `y` instead of integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks aosmith, this works:

```
legendData <- as.factor(c(100, 325, 550, 775, 1000))
legendColors <- c("#FF9DEB", "#9FC5FF", "#00E4D0", "#AAD44D", "#FFAE85")
df <- data.frame(x = legendData, col = legendColors, 
  y = as.factor(rep(1,length(legendData))), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df %>% ggvis(~x, ~y, fill := ~col, strokeWidth := 0) %>%
layer_rects(width = band(), height = band()) %>% hide_axis("x") %>% hide_axis("y") %>%
scale_nominal("x", padding = 0, points = FALSE) %>% 
scale_nominal("y", padding = 0, points = FALSE)
```